# Consumer Producer using message passing (not shared memory)

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, java.util.concurrent, message-passing

I am a little confused about message passing between several threads in Java. In many places it's written that currently it's not supported by the standard ways, but there are some libraries like [kilim](http://www.malhar.net/sriram/kilim/). I've found [java nio](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/nio/channels/package-summary.html).

1. isn't nio for this purpose?
2. what are there the ways of passing data between thread (shared
   memory, sending messages),something else? (java io - is it the way of using shared memory ?)
3. where can I find a sample of implementing Consumer Producer task
   using message passing(not using shared memory)?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Message passing is just a higher-level protocol internally implemented in terms of shared memory. It is typically an API that allows its clients not to share any objects of their own, but that doesn't mean the internals don't share any memory.

Comment: What's the goal here?  Any reason why you aren't using a `BlockingQueue` or other mechanisms.  Why _not_ used shared memory?  Is this an academic question?

Comment: -File,Signal,Socket, Message queue, Pipe, Named pipe, Semaphore,Shared memory,Message passing. types of IPC

Comment: it's only for self studying and for more deep understanding of multithreading. I need to implement CP problem using message passing.

Comment: If it's on the same machine it's probably shared memory, regardless of what it's actually called.